# Прокатить "Матильду" — что это означает?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, глаголы

**ПРОКАТИТЬ**

В словаре:
4. *Разг.* ***Подвергнуть резкой критике*** (в печати, в публичном выступлении).

В печати:
1. Режиссер: *Легче снять кино, чем **прокатить** его в кинотеатрах.*

2.*«Матильду» могут **прокатить.**

Часть уральских кинотеатров откажется от показа фильма.*

В первом и втором случае смысл глагола "прокатить" различен:
**выпустить в прокат** (такого толкования нет в словаре) и **раскритиковать**.

И оба автора правы?

Comment: @Aer Знаю, что после модератора правки делать не принято. Отважилась. Если я не (совсем, очень) права, — дайте знак. Буду знать своё прибалтийское место.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова почему же не принято, вы все правильно сделали :) К сожалению, у меня далеко не всегда хватает времени на качественную правку вопросов, поэтому приходится устранять только самые ужасные ошибки и неточности.

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку.

Answer (score 2):

**Прокатить (1)** ― это организовать прокат фильма, профессиональный жаргон.

**Прокатить (2)** ―  не избрать при баллотировке, забаллотировать (из словаря).

В данном случае ― не допустить фильм  к прокату.

Из словаря: 2. **ПРОКАТ**, 2. Разг. =Кинопрокат. Выпустить фильм в п.

В 2005 году конституцию, разработанную Конвентом о будущем Европы, **прокатили** на референдуме французы и голландцы. [Александр Терентьев. Лиссабонская утопия // «Однако», 2009]

Почему депутаты **прокатили** закон о страховании вкладов [ «Новая газета», 2003.01.02]

Вчера вернулся из Баку, где снимали Райкина. С Ленинской премией его ― увы ― **прокатили**. Ужасно несправедливо. [Василий Катанян. Лоскутное одеяло (1960-1969)]

Comment: Значит, в предложении Легче снять кино, чем прокатить его в кинотеатрах - прокатить - организовать прокат.

Comment: Да, я думаю, это так. Понятна мысль режиссера: снять фильм - это всегда затрата больших усилий, но организация  его  проката  в данном случае оказалась задачей еще более сложной.

Answer (score 1):

> И оба автора правы?

Скорее оба неправы.
Здесь разные значения, одно разговорное (прокатить - не допустить к чему либо, забалотировать т . п.), второе - совсем уж окказиональное (прокатить - провести **прокат** фильма.

Первое здесь в принципе возможно, если текст не слишком официальный, хотя возможно во избежание двусмысленности, стоит взять в кавычки, значение-то переносное, хотя и оно не очень подходит для конкретной ситуации. Ни жюри/выборов, ни голосования, ни соревновательности (то, на чем "прокатывают") ведь не предполагается. Тут скорее более подошло бы "зарезать" - в значении "запретить".

Что касается второго "прокатить в кинотеатрах", то это какой-то новояз. На профжаргон как-то не тянет. Значение в общем-то понятно, но никакими словарями, как я понимаю, пока не фиксируется. тут, имхо, даже кавычки не помогут.